# Collating Sequence Not supported by operating system

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6, sql-server-2000, database-connection

I am moving from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008. The SQL 2000 is on a Server 2003. SQL 2008 is on a Server 2008. I have imported my database successfully. I am able to perform queries and they work fine. I use a VB6 program running in the IDE to update the database.

When my VB6 program runs on a server 2003 the program will connect using the following connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;DATABASE=mydbname;SERVER=my ip;DRIVER={SQL SERVER};UID=myuser;PWD=mypw;
```

Using the above connection string, I can connect with no errors to either SQL 2000 or the new SQL 2008 database. On the Server 2008, there is no SQLOLEDB driver show, so I have to use the new SQLNCLI10 provider

```
CCTdbConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServer\My InstanceName;Database=MyDB;UID=myuser;PWD=mypw;
```

Here's the problem. When I am running on the Server 2008 I get the error  3228 Selected collating sequence not supported by the operating system.  If I hit debug and try again, or stop the program and try again it gets past that error until I reopen the IDE. Then I get a 2nd error encountered is an error 3027 Can Not Update. Database or object is read-only! This never goes away and I'm dead.

Answer (score 2):

After Much research, I have found the answer. SQL 2005 and up apparently require a Unique Key Index exist on every single table that is accessed using ODBC or OLEDB. 
This Cures the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the code: don't use the IDE?

Related [KS KB article 246167](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;246167)

Comment: That cured the Collating Sequence Error Messages. Wonder Why?
The data base is sill 'Read Only'
I Can use SQL Profiler on this same machine with the same credentials and all queries work.

Comment: BTW: This is in VB6, the KB article is for EXCEL